# cloud-init: Can I install from RPM using cloud-config?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, cloud-init

I'm new to cloud-init and I'm trying to install a certain package from an RPM file. Is there a way to do it from the packages or yum_repos modules? For the time being I'm installing it from bash using the runcmd module:

```
#cloud-config    
runcmd:
  - [yum, install, -y, https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm]
```

But I'd really like to avoid this since all the other dependencies are being installed from the packages module.

Comment: That seems fine. I mean, you could try passing the url to the package module in lieu of a package name and see what happens...it *might* just work, and if it doesn't, you already have a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try that.

Comment: Thanks @larsks, it worked!! Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that you can just list the URL along with other packages in the package module. Assuming that the module ultimately just calls out to `yum install` (or the equivalent via the api), you can use package names and urls interchangeably. And if it doesn't work, you already have a workaround :).

```
#cloud-config
packages:
  - https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
```